# SQL query for salary increase

Tags: sql

I came up with following query which is not so challenging to resolve but still I think there might be better approach for this. Any suggessions?

I have got following table:

tb_Salary

```
EmpID DeptID Salary
---------------------
1  1  20000
2  1  20000
3  2  30000
4  2  800
5  2  200
```

I want to increase the salary of employees by Rs. 1000 only when the average salary in the department is more than 35000.

Is this possible using single update query?

I did this in following way. But seems that it is not that smart solution.

```
UPDATE  tb_Salary t1
SET  t1.Salary=t1.Salary+1000
WHERE  35000 < (select AVG(t2.Salary) from tb_Salary t2 WHERE t2.DeptID=t1.DeptID)
```

Comment: Your SQL statement works. So it would help us if you clarified what you meant by isn't a "smart solution"

Comment: Ya it works.. but I thought that it might be possible in single query i.e. without using inner query may be just by adding group by and having clause in some other way.

Comment: Anil, it is one query. Either way the DBMS is going to have to make the same 2 steps. If there were some other clever way, likely it would be _less_ efficient than this.

Comment: gr8... so that means I am already smart! :)
Thanks to all for your comments..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is the way to go.

Comment: Hi neolace,
it's giving error for aggregate function.

.. Also my query had some errors which I have corrected now.

Comment: Where is the answer

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE  tb_salary
    SET tb_salary.salary = tb_salary + 1000
FROM    tb_salary
        INNER JOIN
        (SELECT   avg(salary) AS avg_salary,
                  deptID
         FROM     tb_salary
         GROUP BY tb_salary.deptID
         HAVING   avg(salary) > 10000) AS salary_increase
        ON salary_increase.deptID = tb_salary.deptID;
```

I don't have time to test this, so it might not working.
Usually I avoid multiple "Where" condition because it is not effective.

Comment: Why would you post something that's not tested?

Answer (score 0):

```
update employee 
  set salary=salary+1000
  where deptid in (select deptid from employee group by deptid having sum(salary)>35000);
```

Comment: Your are comparing `sum(salary)`. OP was asking "when the _average_ salary ... is more than 35000". So, that's probably an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE  employee_salary
SET ICT_ salary.salary=5000
FROM ICT_salary
INNER JOIN
(SELECT average (salary. department I'd.
HAVING avr (salary) >5000 AS salary increase
ON salaro_increase.depID=ICT_salary. deptID;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).